# Are there counterspell rules in DnD3.X?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

Are there counterspell rules in DnD3.X?

Comment: This question is rather light.  Can you add some context?

Comment: This question appears to a poor fit for Stack Exchange because it does not show any research effort.

Comment: The question is from when the site was in beta 4 years ago. We were trying to define its scope, and there was a concerted effort to ask more questions with concrete answers.

Comment: @LeguRi That's fine, it was important in its day. But Stack doesn't have grandfather clauses, so when site guidelines evolve older questions that no longer fit get closed when we run across them.

Comment: Closing the question makes definitely makes sense in that case. The slew of down votes is more puzzling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes,

<sub>distilled from [d20srd.org](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#counterspells)</sub>

To counterspell you must:

- Ready an action to counterspell a specific target
- Make a spellcraft check of DC15 + spell level as a free action to identify the spell
- Cast the identical spell to counter it
- Metamagic effects are not considered (you can counter an enlarged fireball with a normal fireball)
- Some spells are specifically made to counter other spells as per the spell description (example [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/enlargePerson.htm)/[Reduce Person](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reducePerson.htm))
- [Dispel Magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) can also be used to counter spells.  In this case you do not need to make a spellcraft check, but you do need a dispel check.
- A [Ring of Counterspells](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#counterspells) can be used to counter one specific spell cast upon the wearer.  It requires no readying, or even knowledge of the spell by the wearer.

Comment: There's an important first step that's omitted here; you must select your opponent by readying an action.

Comment: Jadasc is definitely right, also you may want to describe the spellcraft check and it's level limits.  Also you might want to mention the *Ring of Counterspell*.

Comment: @Jadasc, @CRoss - Thanks for the comments, I've accommodated both.

Comment: There's also the Improved Counterspell feat which lets you counter a spell with any spell from the same school, as long as it is of higher level.